# Android Maps V2 Crashing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My big project for today was migrating my app to the new Google Maps API V2. However, I am hitting an error now that I can't seem to find the root cause of.

My stack trace looks like this:

```
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start        activity ComponentInfo{com.mobile.barwatch/com.mobile.barwatch.TestActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at com.mobile.barwatch.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:18)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     ... 11 more
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at maps.y.z.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at maps.y.z.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at maps.y.z.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at maps.y.ae.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at maps.y.bu.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at maps.y.p.onCreateView(Unknown  Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.d$4.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4704)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634):     ... 20 more
```

My activity class looks like this:

```
package com.mobile.barwatch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
import com.google.android.gms.common.*;
import com.mobile.barwatch.tasks.*;
import com.mobile.barwatch.models.Constants;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_screen);              
    }
}
```

My layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mapview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

And the relevant parts of my manifest look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobile.barwatch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <permission android:name="com.mobile.barwatch.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <permission android:name="com.mobile.barwatch.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mobile.barwatch.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mobile.barwatch.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application    
        android:allowBackup="true"    
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_barwatch"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ....
    <activity android:name="TestActivity" 
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.xx"
               android:value="xx"/>       
    </application>       
</manifest>
```

Im really banging my head against the wall on this one so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And your stack trace looks like?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.` Do you have that in your manifest specified with what the stack trace asks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay thanks to responses by A--C and qzikl I was able to find out what my problem was. When filling out my manifest, I had:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.xx"
            android:value="xx"/>
```

where xx was my api key. In actuality, it should be:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xx"/>
```

So what was causing all my errors was that I was filling in API_KEY with my api key where I was only supposed to do that for the value.

Comment: Also, make sure it is in the <application> element.

Comment: later then I was getting issue of sha1 hash. Updated api key value in google developer console and bang! Thank you. Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your LogCat showed another error like:

> 12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class fragment

and it's the clue of all problems. As you see the "class" contained in  has wrong expression, but at this moment I dont know the solution.

Comment: The problem is caused by wrong implements com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment to your application project. To properly display maps you must add external jar file from android sample contains maps with api v2.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace includes your answer:

12-17 17:16:20.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3634): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

You need to get an API key and include it in your manifest. It looks like you've got something in there for that, but perhaps it was edited out?

Comment: I do have an api key added, just commented out in the question for security..I've tried regenerating an api key as well but no dice

Answer (score 0):

Try folow this for obtaining NEW API KEY https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw